# Ruby,CSV and pdf's

Tags: ruby, csv, pdf

So I am converting urls into images and downloading them into a document. The file can be an .jpg or .pdf. I can successfully download the pdf and there is something on the pdf (in form of memory) but when I try to open the pdf, adobe reader does not recognize it and deem it broken.

Here is a link to one of the URLs - http://www.finfo.se/www.artdb.finfo.se/cgi-bin/lankkod.dll/lev?knr=7770566&art=001317514&typ=PI

And here is the code =>

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'tempfile'
require 'uri'
require 'csv'

DOWNLOAD_DIR = "#{Dir.pwd}/PI/"
CSV_FILE = "#{Dir.pwd}/konvertera4.csv"

def downloadFile(id, url, format)

  begin
    open("#{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}", "w") do |file|
      file << open(url).read
      puts "Successfully downloaded #{url} to #{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}"
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "#{e} #{url}"
  end
end


CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, headers: true, col_sep: ";") do |row|
  puts row
  next unless row[0] && row[1]
  id = row[0]
  format = row[1].match(/PI\.(.+)$/)&.captures.first
  puts format
  #format = "pdf"
  #format = row[1].match(/BD\.(.+)$/)&.captures.first
  url = row[1].gsub ".pdf", ""
  downloadFile(id, url, format)
end
```

Comment: Is the linked PDF supposed to be broken? Because I can open it just fine.

Comment: That's the thing. The URL works perfectly fine, I have already converted around 2000 urls, but from nowhere this happened, the file is either "corrupted" or "broken". I can not for the love of me figure out why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using wb instead of w:

```
open("#{DOWNLOAD_DIR}#{id}.#{format}", "wb")
```

Comment: Also if you're working on Linux, you can make you're download function a lot simpler by just using: `wget #{url}`

Comment: This solved everything, thank you so much. To think that a single letter changes everything. You saved me big time <3